# How to covert std::string to NSString?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, nsstring

You can read code from the picture.The function `getResult()` return a std::string ,like" `<s> 启 动 <unk> <_Apps_> 照相机 </_Apps_> </s> \n-4.93`",but the `result` is garbled,and the NSString `res` is nil. 
And I used lldb command `po`,find the `_data`,what is it? Why the  NSString `res` is nil.

[image]

This is the code causing problems:

```
std:string result = getResult();

NSString *res = [NSString stringWithCString:result.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the `getResult`function code:

```
std::string getResult()
{
    char *res = NULL;

    asGetResult(&res);

    if (res != NULL) {

     printf("asGetResult = %s \n",res);
     return std::string(res);
    }
   else
   {
     return std::string("");
   }
```

}

And the function `getResult` is included in a static library,which is written by c++.

Comment: What does `getResult` look like? (Post text, not screenshots.)

Comment: I have write the `getResult` function.Can you explain the reason?

Comment: What character encoding is your string using?  If care is used and you know your encodings, `std::string` can be used with Unicode, but it's messy.

Comment: The `printf("asGetResult = %s \n",res);`  can print `<s> 启 动 <unk> <_Apps_> 照相机 </_Apps_> </s> \n-4.93` every time.